# How to create an if else condition with ArcGIS Javascript API for slider and imageLayers from switch statement

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

The code below is the switch statement that I am currently using.  I can't seem to get the values (case) to match up with the horizontal slider I am using (4 unique values-each layer).  I was thinking of trying an if else condition instead.  Anyone have the best way to accomplish this?

```
function setPixelFilter() {
        var val = slider.get("value");
        switch (val) {
          case 0:
            var imageLayer = new ArcGISImageServiceLayer("https://...ImageServer")
            map.addLayer(imageLayer)
            break;
          case 100/3:
            var imageLayer = new ArcGISImageServiceLayer("https://...ImageServer")
            map.addLayer(imageLayer)                
            break;
          case 100/3*2:
            var imageLayer = new ArcGISImageServiceLayer("https://...ImageServer")
            map.addLayer(imageLayer)
            break;
          case 100:
            var imageLayer = new ArcGISImageServiceLayer("https://...ImageServer")
            map.addLayer(imageLayer)
            break;
```

Comment: you need to try setting a breakpoint in your browser developer tools to step through the code and inspect the value of 'val'

Comment: The slider.value is 5.5, 6, 7, 8 respectively.

Comment: none of which equal 0, 33.3, 66.6 or 100.  or am i missing something?

Comment: Yeah sorry, 0, 33.3, 66.6, 100 have to be in a percentage since that is the position of the horizontal slider.  At that percentage (33.3) value 5.5 is pulled which equates to that imageLayer.  I figured out the issue I was having but am running into another issue of the layers not redrawing after each slide which I think Ill ask in a separate question.

Comment: What I was going to try to do as a work around so one layer draws and removes the previous layers at each horizontal value, was do an if else statement instead of using the switch.